# Skipping acquire of configuration file

Tags: debian, apt, raspberry-pi

I installed Raspberry Pi OS Lite to run Unifi Network Controller. But I'm confused about the packages I need to configure.
I get  these notices:

```
kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease [15.0 kB]
Ign:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease
Hit:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release
Hit:6 https://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease
Fetched 107 kB in 2s (62.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'rpi/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'ubiquiti/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://www.ui.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
```

```
kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ lscpu
Architecture:                    aarch64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
Vendor ID:                       ARM
Model:                           3
Model name:                      Cortex-A72
Stepping:                        r0p3
CPU max MHz:                     1800.0000
CPU min MHz:                     600.0000
BogoMIPS:                        108.00
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       192 KiB
L2 cache:                        1 MiB
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Not affected
Vulnerability Retbleed:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Vulnerable
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Vulnerable
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
```

```
kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I deleted raspi.list but it didn't help.
How can I get rid of these warning because I think they are the reason my unifi service is failing?
Can someone explain me which architecture and distro version packages I need to choose in the future?

Edit: I understand now that Raspbian and Raspberry Pi OS are not the same.
I removed all Stretch occurrences and the notices are gone.
Still errors on Unifi service but I will use the link in the comment for that topic.

Comment: Not at all, I used the official raspberry pi imager and installed the 'Lite' version, because I wanted to have a headless version.
But it says version 11, not 9.
I guess you didn't see my cat /etc/os-release

Comment: Ah - so it's just the name :-D The current name is Raspberry Pi OS, I fixed it for you. Raspbian was still Stretch-based, hence the confusioning :-) Anyhoo, I'd remove the Stretch repo and see what happens. Follow instructions [here](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/220066768-UniFi-Network-Updating-Third-Party-non-Console-UniFi-Network-Applications-Linux-Advanced-). Please don't put new info in comments, rather [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/742322/edit) the question so all relevant info is immediately available.

Comment: [This](https://community.ui.com/questions/Step-By-Step-Tutorial-Guide-Raspberry-Pi-with-UniFi-Controller-and-Pi-hole-from-scratch-headless/e8a24143-bfb8-4a61-973d-0b55320101dc) posting in Unifi forum details installation on Raspberry Pi OS, and claims it works with Bullseye. Not with RasPi 4, tho', but there's a link to an alternative script.